# Can a relay be used to power a 3.3 V appliance?

Tags: arduino, relay

I'm a programming student and I got into an Arduino class this semester. Here's some backstory behind this question:

I need to make a Bluetooth module switch modes from master to slave and back, but I found out that the module only switches modes by being unpowered then powered again (and doing some specific things). This means I would have to unpower it manually by unplugging its power, but that'd mean it wouldn't be completely automated, so it's a no-no.

Because of that, I'm considering using a relay to be able to power it down then back on again via code, and found some relays that can be controlled by supplying 3.3-5 V.

However, all relays I've seen state that they work on 30/110/220 V.

So, if I use 3.3/5 V to control the relay, and 5 V to power the module through the relay, will the circuit through the relay work?

Comment: a relay is just a mechanical switch  .... technically, it does not power anything ..... it can be replaced by a piece of wire ..... so, if the circuit will work when a piece of wire is inserted, then the relay will also work .................. that said, are you sure that the module does not have a reset pin or a reset command? ..... resetting the module may be the same as power cycling the module

Comment: Yeah, I probably made some bad wording there, but I mean that: if I can supply enough power to switch the circuits, can I pass any voltage through the circuit, right?

Comment: It has! There's a EN pin which, when not powered, disables the module. I tried it and it works. I just need to test if disabling the module actually turns it off(for resetting purposes), instead of just making it stop until enabled again, else I'll still need a relay. Thanks!

Comment: An Hc-05. By the way, it works! The EN pin counts as powering off. I still need a relay to supply 3.3V to a pin so it can enter AT mode, but thank you so much!

Comment: No, I don't have a relay right now, so I can't test myself.

For the bluetooth module to enter AT command mode, I need to supply 3.3V(PWM doesn't work, it has to be the 3.3V out from the board) to a KEY Pin on the side of the board while the board is off, then turn it on. To turn it off, the EN pin must be off, which I can do via arduino. So the only problem now is that I need a relay to shut off the 3.3v to this KEY pin so I can exit AT command mode and go back to master/slave modes.

Comment: if you are using an arduino, then control both the EN and KEY pins with arduino directly ..... you already observed that EN does a reset  ........... just make sure that the arduino has 3.3V outputs

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to do that before, but the module didn't respond, so I thought that wouldn't work. The problem however was that it wasn't responding because it required a specific baud rate, so now I'm able to do everything without a relay. Thanks for all your help! The other answer is marked as correct because it answers my initial question but your answers are the ones that really solved my problem.

Comment: thanks, i learned also ... lol .... this is an example of the X-Y problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work.  The voltage requirement you *must* meet is for the coil.  The contacts are rated for the **maximum** voltage they can safely interrupt.  You will start to run into problems with the contacts with very small voltages, but 3.3V is high enough for the vast majority of relays out there to not have a problem.

Comment: So basically as long as I can supply 5v to switch the circuits on/off, the circuit itself carries any voltage up to the max switching voltage?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the current the module consumes, you could power it directly off one of the digital outputs of the Arduino, or if it's more than that use a P-FET to switch the supply to the module, but there are plenty of relay modules available that can run from an Arduino, they have a transistor on board that reduces the load the 5V coil takes from the Arduino output.[image]

Comment: Powering the module straight from the arduino... of course! I had completely forgotten that my board suports this.


https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/PWM


If I put on a 100% duty cycle, it'll be supplying a steady 5V until I disable it, which solves part of the problem(or the entire problem, if the HC-05 I'll use has a KEY pin). Thanks!


If the HC-05 does not have a KEY pin however, I still need a relay(instead of 2), so I can supply a steady 3.3v (pwm simulates 3.3v, but by floating between on and off, so it won't work).

Comment: Digital out is better than pwm for this. But I'm sure your Bluetooth module uses more than 20 ma. So a relay is best. A transistor could work too.

Comment: I just tried it and unfortunately the module does not turn on when trying to power it through PWM/Digital high. It only turns on when connected to 5v.

Comment: I tried mine and it does power on, but the spec sheet for the module says current consumption is about 10mA and 30mA once connected, so it's a bit much for a direct connection.

Comment: Apparently my module has a pin that disables the module when not powered(the EN pin), so hopefully I can just leave the Vcc connected to the 5V out and just use the EN pin for rebooting. I just need to test now if using this pin counts as "powering off" for changing into AT command mode.

Comment: It does, but supplying 3.3v through PWM to the KEY pin (so it can enter AT command mode) doesn't work. So I still need a relay, but for different reasons now...